# Is it possible to disallow Instance creation from AMI with Production tag in a non-production environment?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

For an AMI or RDS Snapshot with a specific Tag (`Key=Environment, Value=Production`), is there any way using IAM, in AWS to disallow creation of instances from that AMI in Non-Production environment - say a VPC not tagged with `Key=Environment, Value=Production` ?

Restricting Instance creation from specifically tagged AMI to be created in one particular VPC would be good too.

Thankyou.